# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure'

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I am trying to run [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/tree/master/azure-iot-device#linux) sample code on my windows development machine.  The moment I try to run [simple_send_message.py](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/blob/master/azure-iot-device/samples/simple_send_message.py), I am getting following error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "msg.py", line 3, in <module>
    from azure.iot.device.aio import IoTHubDeviceClient
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure'
```

**Dev Environment Details**

```
    PS C:\data\code\youtube\iothub\python-send-message> py --version
    Python 3.8.5

    PS C:\data\code\youtube\iothub\python-send-message>pip install azure-iot-device
    Requirement already satisfied: azure-iot-device in c:\users\heman\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (2.1.4)
    Requirement already satisfied: PySocks in c:\users\heman\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from azure-iot-device) (1.7.1)
    Requirement already satisfied: six<2.0.0,>=1.12.0 in c:\users\heman\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from azure-iot-device) (1.15.0)
    Requirement already satisfied: paho-mqtt<2.0.0,>=1.4.0 in c:\users\heman\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from azure-iot-device) (1.5.0)
    Requirement already satisfied: requests-unixsocket<1.0.0,>=0.1.5 in c:\users\heman\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from azure-iot-device) (0.2.0)
    Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>1.21.1; python_version != "3.4" in c:\users\heman\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from azure-iot-device) (1.24.2)
    Requirement already satisfied: requests<3.0.0,>=2.20.0 in c:\users\heman\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from azure-iot-device) (2.21.0)
    Requirement already satisfied: janus==0.4.0; python_version >= "3.5" in c:\users\heman\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from azure-iot-device) (0.4.0)
    Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\heman\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.20.0->azure-iot-device) (2019.3.9)
    Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in c:\users\heman\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.20.0->azure-iot-device) (2.8)
    Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\heman\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.20.0->azure-iot-device) (3.0.4)

PS C:\data\code\youtube\iothub\python-send-message> python --version
Python 3.7.1
PS C:\data\code\youtube\iothub\python-send-message> pip --version
pip 20.2.1 from c:\users\heman\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)
PS C:\data\code\youtube\iothub\python-send-message>
```

I saw [couple of](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/issues/296) threads discussing same issue but not sure what is the resolution.

Any pointers, how to resolve this on a windows machine?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with pip3?

```
pip3 install azure-iot-device
```

Comment: yes, I have tried with pip3.  It looks like my windows having trouble handling multiple versions of Python.  The same thing worked very well without any issue on my Raspberry Pi device

Answer (score 0):

## Check installations

Please check your Python and pip installation on your device with the following commands:

`python --version` or `python3 --version`

`pip --version`

---

## Install under directory

If everything goes right, try this:
Try installing the package, here `azure`, in your project directory. This might work. For example:

`$ cd [Project-Folder]`

`pip install azure-iot-device`

Comment: I have updated my post with additional information.  But still no luck.

Comment: Very very sorry friend. I'm a Mac and Linux user.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and could not find any solution to this. Here is what worked for me.

Uninstalled python from the system, cleared the python home path in the environment variables and reinstalled python.

My previous version of python is 3.10.0 and the latest version installed is 3.11.1. After fresh installation, I have used the following command from import the module from the project directory.

```
pip install azure-iot-device
```

I no longer see the error after trying the above steps.

Answer (score 0):

In terminal, navigate to location where file exists, and run from the command line as below

```
python3 filename.py
```